# How to open the ColorPicker's "Custom Colors" window by clicking an independent menu item?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, color-picker

I'm trying to open `ColorPicker`'s `Custom Colors` window by clicking on one of the menu items from my popup `ContextMenu`.

```
ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem menuItemBgColor = new MenuItem("Background Color");
menuItemBgColor.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {
        // Open ColorPicker's "Custom Colors" window.
    }
});
contextMenu.getItems().add(menuItemBgColor);
```

However, I do not have a clue how can I achieve that. I tried to use a `CustomMenuItem`:

```
CustomMenuItem cmi = new CustomMenuItem(new ColorPicker());
```

...but the added color picker was "un-clickable".

What I want to achieve, is to open a `Custom Colors` window by clicking on the given standard `MenuItem`:

[image]

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution. Did you managed to solve the problem?